# how to double the size of a linked list in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

For example,given a list such as [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
After I call doublelist(), the origianl list should be [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5 ,5]

Here is my code:

```
public void stutter(){
    ListNode curr = front;
        while(curr!=null){
        ListNode tempNode = new ListNode();
        tempNode.data=curr.data;
        tempNode.next=curr.next;
        curr.next=tempNode;
        curr=tempNode.next;
    }  
}
```

My question is how do I write this method without use  tempNode.data=curr.data?

ListNode.java

```
public class ListNode {
    public int data;       // data stored in this node
    public ListNode next;  // a link to the next node in the list

}
```

Comment: Why??  The very nature of this problem involves making copies of nodes, so of course you will be copying `.data` from one node to another node.  What are you trying to accomplish, and why?  And what did you expect the resulting list to look like (i.e. what are the nodes and the links going to look like)?

Comment: how would you assign a node to current node without creating?.. you'll need to create a node and that's what you are doing by creating temp node

Comment: How do I copy node? i am new to java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the actual intent of your program?

You can create a *copy* constructor for `ListNode` that can do half the work for you.

```
class ListNode {
    public int data; // data stored in this node
    public ListNode next; // a link to the next node in the list

    public ListNode() { } //Default constructor. You will need this

    // Create this constructor for ListNode
    public ListNode(ListNode other){
        this.data = other.data;
        this.next = other.next;
    }
}
```

Then, inside your `stutter` method,

```
public void stutter() {
    ListNode curr = front;
    while (curr != null) {
        ListNode tempNode = new ListNode(curr);// Using the copy constructor
        curr.next = tempNode;
        curr = tempNode.next;
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `Cloneable` interface inside your `ListNode`

```
public class ListNode implements Cloneable{
    public int data;       // data stored in this node
    public ListNode next;  // a link to the next node in the list

    @Override
    public ListNode clone()  {
      ListNode cloned = null;
      try {
          cloned = (ListNode) super.clone();
      }finally {
          return cloned;
      }
    }
}
```

You can call `ListNode temp = curr.clone();` to create a new node.